# Conda incorrectly says I have no space left on device when I do indeed have space. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, conda

Using Conda package manager, I get this `[Errno 28] No space left on device` message when I try to install a new package in an existing environment or when I try to create a new environment.

I have enough space on disk based on `df` and `du`. In fact, I have around 150G available.

How do I fix this error? Is there a way to print out the directory where conda is running into the out of space error or some other way to debug this.

This is a new error in that in the past I've been able to add packages or conda environments.

(I don't know if this is related but I also have not been able to update my conda version. I've entered `conda update -n base -c defaults conda` but `conda -V` still gives `conda 4.12.0`)

I'm on a cluster and using Red Hat Enterprise Linux (VERSION="8.8 (Ootpa)")

```bash
$ df -hiT /[OUR_DIR]/[MY_NAME]/

Filesystem  Type Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
[redacted]  nfs4   1.6G  1.1M  1.6G    1% [redacted]
```

Comment: Did you check `df -i`?

Comment: Could you provide the output of `df -hiT`?

Comment: I'm using my school's cluster and so I blanked out some info. But I edited my post to add output of `df -hiT`